# NPM: how to specify registry to publish in the command line?

Tags: npm, nexus3

I'm testing a new version of our npm packages registry. I'd like to run a job in our CI server specifying a registry different of the default.

I tried to execute `npm publish --registry "http://nexus.dsv.myhost/nexus/repository/npmjs-registry` but it didn't work. It was published to the default registry.

How do I specify a different registry while running `npm publish`. It is a scoped package.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It sounds like you have a scope-specific registry configured somewhere in your npm config.

npm will merge your global, local and CLI-provided config. But any scope-specific config will take precedence over unscoped config regardless of where each of them are defined.

For example, if you have `@myscope:registry=xyz` in your `~/.npmrc` file, that will take precedence over `--registry=abc` provided on the CLI, because a scope-specific registry always overrides the unscoped registry.

However, you can also pass a scope-specific registry on the CLI itself like this:

```sh
npm publish --@myscope:registry=http://nexus.dsv.myhost/nexus/repository/npmjs-registry
```

Note that because of how `nopt` (which is what npm uses under the hood to parse the CLI options) parses freeform switches, the `=` sign here is required.  If you use a space instead, it won't work as expected.

Comment: the note on the equal sign for the registry param just saved me. thanks

Answer (score 59):

There's multiple ways to accomplish this.

1. use `npm config` to [set the registry globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config#set):

   ```sh
   npm config set registry http://nexus.dsv.myhost/nexus/repository/npmjs
   ```
2. use `npm config` to [set the registry for the package scope](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope#associating-a-scope-with-a-registry):

   ```sh
   npm config set @<your scope here>:registry http://nexus.dsv.myhost/nexus/repository/npmjs
   ```
3. configure your package.json with a [publish config](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#publishconfig):

   ```json
   {
     ...
     "publishConfig": {
       "registry": "http://nexus.dsv.myhost/nexus/repository/npmjs"
     },
     ...
   }
   ```
4. use `npmrc` to [configure the registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc)

   ```
   registry=http://nexus.dsv.myhost/nexus/repository/npmjs
   ```

Comment: The `npm config` does not work, because I have a shared Node installation. It is a CI server. That would change the configuration for everything that is run in the server. I just want to change it for a specific job. It would be better to configure something at the command line, so I don't need to change the code.

Comment: Your CI job can generate an `.npmrc` file at the root of the package before attempting to publish if you need this to be specific to the job. I updated my answer to include details about the npmrc file.

Answer (score 3):

You can also publish directly to a scoped registry by adding the `--scope` parameter, where that scope is already defined in your .npmrc file. I could not find any documentation on this feature, so documenting here:

### Given .npmrc

```
@myscope=https://my.custom.registry.url
```

### Command to publish

```
npm publish --scope=@myscope
```

This will publish the package to your scoped/private registry.

I found this particularly useful when consuming/creating NPM packages for Azure DevOps / Azure Artifacts feeds, where we have decided to NOT use upstream sources, and instead use scope to pull/push packages to our private registry.

> Note that doing it this way requires your private registry to have `@myscope/package-name` as the actual package names. See [this microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops#scopes) for notes.

### Azure Artifacts Example Package

Per the note above, here's how your packages you're creating should look when using scope for a private repo + the public npmjs.org registry.

#### package.json:

```
...
  "name": "@myscope/my-private-package",
...
```