# How to use npm's dist-tag in conjunction with semvar versions?

Tags: javascript, npm, tags, versioning

I have a private npm library. We are using semvar approach and version our projects via:

```
npm version {patch, minor, major}
```

So that users can install it via:

```
npm install mylib@1.5
npm install mylib@2.3.7
...
```

Now, I have run into the use-case that I want to give developers early access to an unstable version of my library.

It seems that `dist-tag` should fit my needs. Therefore, I want to release a `beta` dist-tag so that developers can install that unstable state via

```
npm install mylib@beta
```

So within my unstable branch, I tried publishing the beta branch but got the error:

```
npm publish --tag beta

npm ERR! code EPUBLISHCONFLICT
npm ERR! publish fail Cannot publish over existing version.
npm ERR! publish fail Update the 'version' field in package.json and try again.
npm ERR! publish fail 
npm ERR! publish fail To automatically increment version numbers, see:
npm ERR! publish fail     npm help version
```

This confuses me.

I want to avoid bumping the semvar version to begin with. I was expecting this to only publish its current state as a npm dist-tag to the repository. (And that I could push whatever I want to that tag name as it is a meta-pointer.)

Only once my branch becomes stable and is merged into the main branch, I intended the version bump (`minor`, in this case).

So just for trying it out, I bumped the version before and then published the beta tag, yet this also publishes the newly created minor version, making it available ahead of release time which is not want I want as now people could jump into an unstable future version of mine.

I don't understand how dist-tags and package's versions are supposed to be used in conjunction with the semvar versions and why I would need to bump the version for a tag as well.

Comment: It seems what I want to achieve is the snapshot approach. I found this library, looking forward into this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-snapshot

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156766/using-snapshot-in-private-npm-like-in-maven